# tikz-3dplot: How to get a coordinate system with costum axes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

What do I have to set to get a coordinate sytem like
[image]

**MWE:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
%\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{30}{45}{0}
%\tdplotsetcoord{point}{1}{33}{44}
%\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{00}{0}{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
tdplot_main_coords,
%tdplot_rotated_coords,
]
\foreach \P/\s/\Pos in {(1,0,0)/x/below, (0,1,0)/y/left, (0,0,1)/z/right} 
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- \P node[\Pos, pos=0.9,inner sep=2pt]{$\s$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired coordinate system is not an orthographic projection and can thus not obtained with `tikz-3dplot` (unless you overrule it by hand).

Comment: Can I create something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a48W.png ?
I want the origin to be the foremost point and the axes to go backwards.

Comment: @cis I am currently traveling and cannot see figures because they get censored away.